# Tage wie diese/dieser/diesen

Tags: difference, grammatical-case, grammatical-number

I've stumbled across two German songs with similar titles. First is [Tage wie diese](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107859433214/) with phrases like:

- **Tage wie diese** (plural nominative?)
- **Tagen wie diesem**

and second is [Tage wie dieser](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/118791/) with:

- **Tage wie dieser**
- **Tage wie diesen**
- **an diesen Tagen** (plural dative?)

What are the differences between diese/dieser/diesen in this example and in which cases are all the listed phrases?

Comment: _diese_: nom./acc. plur.; _dieser_: nom. sing., gen. plur.; _diesem_: dat. sing.; _diesen_: acc. sing., dat. plur.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two differences here, case and number. Let's take a look at some examples.

---

Nominative Case

> Ein Tag wie dieser (Tag).

(A day like this(*or that*) day)

(Sg+Sg)

(You're talking about a specific day, compared with another specific day.)

> Ein Tag wie diese (Tage).

(A day like these days)

(Sg+Pl)

(You're talking about a specific day, compared with a common feature of several other days.)

> Tage wie dieser (Tag).

(Days like this one)

(Pl+Sg)

(You're talking about several days, all similar in one feature to a certain other day.)

> Tage wie diese (Tage).

(Days like these days)

(Pl+Pl)

(You're talking about several days that all share a particular feature or features with some other days.)

---

Genitive Case

> Wie schön war doch der Morgen des Tages wie dieser.

(Oh how beautiful was the morning of a day like this one)

(Sg+Sg)

> Wie schön war doch der Morgen des Tages wie diese.

(Oh how beautiful was the morning of a day like these days)

(Sg+Pl)

> Wie schön war doch der Morgen der Tage wie dieser.

(Oh how beautiful was the morning of days like this one)

(Pl+Sg)

> Wie schön war doch der Morgen der Tage wie diese.

(Oh how beautiful was the morning of days like these)

(Pl+Pl)

---

Dative Case

> Er geht einem Tag wie diesem aus dem Weg.

(He avoids a day like this one) (=He does his best to avoid such situations.)

(Sg+Sg)

> Er geht einem Tag wie diesen aus dem Weg.

(He avoids a day like these days)

(Sg+Pl)

> Er geht Tagen wie diesem aus dem Weg.

(He avoids days like this one)

(Pl+Sg)

> Er geht Tagen wie diesen aus dem Weg.

(He avoids days like these days)

(Pl+Pl)

---

Accusative Case

> Ich wünsche mir einen Tag wie diesen.

(I am hoping for a day like this one)

(Sg+Sg)

> Ich wünsche mir einen Tag wie diese.

(I am hoping for a day like these days)

(Sg+Pl)

> Ich wünsche mir Tage wie diesen.

(I am hoping for days like this one)

(Pl+Sg)

> Ich wünsche mir Tage wie diese.

(I am hoping for days like these days)

(Pl+Pl)